# Port iOS5 app layout to iOS8

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, ios8, interface-builder

I have an old iOS that was originally built for iOS5 that I need to port to iOS8.
The code base seems fine, it works well but the design uses iOS5 interface elements for their design (they're the stock Xcode elements).
Is there a way that I can migrate these to the iOS8 styling?

Comment: The `UIControls` will be automatically changed to the iOS 8 versions when you open the app.  The biggest changes will be implementing autolayout (and size classes) to support larger screens, the conversion to 64-bit while preserving 32-bit compatibility (e.g. ensuring files are written / read correctly + possibly other stuff) and finally the way view controllers underlap the status bar / navigation bar. You may also be using deprecated API. But before doing anything - BACKUP YOUR PROJECT. You may also want to move it to Git before opening it up. Then convert one view controller at a time.

Comment: Thanks mate. Auto layout for some reason seems fine. The conversion to 64 bits worries me a little but I believe it should be mainly changing config files as the app doesn't do anything fancy. In terms of deprecated APIs, using them would crash the app when testing right? My project is already on Github but thanks for the reminder.

Comment: How do I get the iOS stock elements instead of the old ones?

Comment: I'm amazed Autolayout is working fine but, if so, that's a large amount of work you won't have to do. After the conversion, check using each of the simulators that the screens are re-sizing and check that `Dynamic Type` doesn't screw up the app (`Dynamic Type` is changing the font size in settings). Apple produced at least two sets of info to read through for 64-bit conversion; just do an internet search and they'll be in the Apple docs somewhere. If you use a deprecated API, I doubt you'll crash unless it's really old API but you should get warnings. Fix them all. Are you already using ARC?

Comment: The app isn't using ARC no. It was started in 2010. I'm also really surprised that auto layout works fine - but just tested up to the 6+ and it works fine. Thanks for the warning on `Dynamic Type`.

Comment: You should also think about converting to ARC (a menu option in Xcode) but this can also be done on a file-by-file basis.

Comment: The app is a bit big so file by file might be a pain. Would much rather use an option in the config if possible yeah.